# flatrepo (monorepo hybrid) webpack cannot find module: 'Invariant' installing invariant has no affect

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, babeljs

I've stumbled upon a weird issue with what I assume to be a webpack or babel compilation problem. This is kind of hard to explain, so bear with me.

**A little background**

We are running a mono-repo hybrid that we're calling a flat repo where it shares a single package.json and uses relative paths for the imports. The reason we're not using Lerna or Yarn workspaces is that flow does not play nicely with a mono-repo without having to transpile the directories and that was a deal breaker at this time. But I digress, this repo is using react/electron and react-native to build out our apps.

Folder Structure

```
project
--apps
----mobile // react native
----web // react/electron
--packages
----foo // generic shared code
----bar
package.json
```

Whenever starting up the electron app, it will start intermittently. Sometimes it will work as expected, but if the package.json file is ever tweaked it may break everything throwing the following error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'invariant' in '/Users/foo/localhost/project/node_modules/react-redux/es/components'
```

Installing invariant does nothing. Re-installing or changing react-redux and respected libraries to different versions do nothing.

I've found a weird workaround that if I have the dev server running and modify the package.json with a `yarn add foo` in a different terminal, that it will sometimes "reset" itself and successfully compile.

My webpack config is a generic version of the ejected CRA config.

I don't believe it to be a config issue though because sometimes it will compile accurately and work. I am at a loss and the google doesn't seem to  have much to offer on the subject. Trying to build the project throws the same error as well.

Thanks for anyone who reads this, I appreciate any help you can offer.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the root of the issue was. But to fix this, I downloaded a fresh CRA and ejected it, copied over the custom monorepo code and tweaked some things, catered to the monorepo, primarily the paths.js file from the ejection. Also took all of the CRA packages and merged them into package.json. A little bit of a roundabout way to get it done but all is well now, it runs and builds successfully.